# How to use BigInteger class?

Tags: java, biginteger

I am having trouble printing numbers past 12!(factorial).
Can someone please help me out? I'm not even sure if I'm using this class correctly.

```
public class Application{

   public static int factorial(int n){

      int index = n;
      int total = 1;
      while(index > 0){
         total *= index;
         index --;
      }

      return total;
   }

   public static void print(int n){
      int index = n;
      while(index > 0){
         BigInteger big = BigInteger.valueOf(factorial(index));
         System.out.println(index + ": " + big);
         index --;
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args){
      int n = 30;
      print(n);

   }
}
```

and this is a snippet of what it prints out:

```
18: -898433024
17: -288522240
16: 2004189184
15: 2004310016
14: 1278945280
13: 1932053504
12: 479001600
```

Comment: BigIntegers are meant to be used to let you calculate big numbers, not to just present them. They solve exactly the problem you are facing now, integer overflow. So use BigInteger to calculate factorials, not only to present them.

Comment: You should use the BigInteger instances for multiplication.

Comment: It seems like you are using `int` values and just assigning them to `BigInteger`

Comment: you need to learn about integer sizes, overflow, and read the documentation of BigInteger to understand what it does

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `BigInteger` in your `factorial` function, not "after you've done the calculation".

Note also that when multiplying `BigInteger`s, use the [`BigInteger.multiply(BigInteger val)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#multiply%28java.math.BigInteger%29) method instead of `*`.

Here's the changed method, which is exactly the same as yours except it uses `BigInteger` instead of `int`:

```
public static BigInteger factorial(int n){
  int index = n;
  BigInteger total = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
  while(index > 0){
     total = total.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(index));
     index --;
  }

  return total;
}
```

Note that also you don't need to convert the return value of the method to a `BigInteger` anymore, e.g. just do:

```
BigInteger big = factorial(index);
```

Here's the output:

```
30: 265252859812191058636308480000000
29: 8841761993739701954543616000000
28: 304888344611713860501504000000
27: 10888869450418352160768000000
26: 403291461126605635584000000
25: 15511210043330985984000000
24: 620448401733239439360000
23: 25852016738884976640000
22: 1124000727777607680000
21: 51090942171709440000
20: 2432902008176640000
19: 121645100408832000
18: 6402373705728000
17: 355687428096000
16: 20922789888000
15: 1307674368000
14: 87178291200
13: 6227020800
12: 479001600
11: 39916800
10: 3628800
9: 362880
8: 40320
7: 5040
6: 720
5: 120
4: 24
3: 6
2: 2
1: 1
```

Comment: two questions: why is typing BigInteger big = factorial(index); enough to get the whole thing. and the other is why is this line necessary BigInteger total = BigInteger.valueOf(1); when we already have this: total = total.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(index)); is it because we need to have two BigInteger type in order to have them multiply each other?

Comment: `BigInteger` is an OBJECT. Think of it as something you can hold in your hand. Imagine a class `Pie` and a method `Pie bake(Apple[] apples, Dough dough)`. `BigInteger` is enough to get the whole thing because, after the method is done, I hand the entire object back to the calling method, in the same way that if I baked you a pie, I would return the entire pie when I was done baking.

Comment: `BigInteger.valueOf(1)` is required as a starting point because it is an Object that is equivalent to the mathematical quantity of 1. So I need to have it for the same reason your original code had `int total = 1`. You use `BigInteger` exactly as you would use a number, except instead of saying `+`, you say `.plus`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are trying to do "big" math with plain integers (declared as `int`, using the multiplication operator `*`) and then wrapping in a BigInteger when you should instead be doing math on BigIntegers directly (e.g. using the [`BigInteger#multiply(...)` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#multiply%28java.math.BigInteger%29):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  BigInteger factorial = BigInteger.ONE;
  for (int i=1; i<=20; i++) {
    factorial = factorial.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
    System.out.println(i + "! = " + factorial);
  }
}

// 1! = 1
// 2! = 2
// 3! = 6
// ...
// 18! = 6402373705728000
// 19! = 121645100408832000
// 20! = 2432902008176640000
```